# Product page is not fully loading

Tags: static-content, refresh-statistics

I am having trouble on some of the product page to get fully loaded. On some of them, even the add to cart button is not clickable until I will refresh the page. Its a random behaviour. Some  I have to refresh multiple time to see the  PayPal button to be loaded on the product page.

I already applied the following steps: Removed all the cache from VAR manually as well.

```
php bin/magento setup:di:compile
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

Comment: Please check the console for JS error and add the same if there is any